# Rails not recognizing Javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using [THIS](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus) screencast to be able select Dynamicaly from regions to countys.

I set up all records in database.
Models have associations and so on. 
But now when I reload page it shows me this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do_cond or ';' or '\n'
_erbout.concat "  countys.push(new Array("; _...
```

So I  think that Rails can't recognize Rails syntax inside javascript file ? Is that true ?
Is there option to make it understand syntax or I need other way around to get going dynamic selections ?

**dynamic_countys.js.erb located in assets/javascript folder.**

```
var countys = new Array();
<% for county in @countys -%>
  countys.push(new Array(<%= county.region_id %>, '<%=h county.name %>', <%= county.id %>));
<% end -%>

function countrySelected() {
  region_id = $('form_region_id').getValue();
  options = $('form_region_id').options;
  options.length = 1;
  countys.each(function(county) {
    if (county[0] == region_id) {
      options[options.length] = new Option(county[1], county[2]);
    }
  });
  if (options.length == 1) {
    $('state_field').hide();
  } else {
    $('state_field').show();
  }
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  countrySelected();
  $('form_region_id').observe('change', countrySelected);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: ruby code in a js file makes my eyes bleed :(

Comment: @nzifnab i understand, but then you can provide me with other solution ? :)

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds You have two options either make it an ajax request and use HTML5 data attributes to get access to your variable or use js inside your template

Comment: When do you think the ERB in anything under the `assets/` directory will be evaluated? How many pages will use your `countrySelected` function? BTW, you're using both "county" and "country"; those are different things, you should be using "country" consistently to avoid insidious and irritating problems with variable names.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks. Actualy I want to use County and Region. Region has many Countys.  countySelected will be used just in _form.html.erb

Comment: @muistooshort After I corrected few mistakes, I get new error-> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass    So it says that my @countys variable is empty? But that is not true. I have over 150records

Comment: That's because the ERB is processed as part of the asset pipeline. That is done before your controllers run so there is no `@countys` when you try to use it. So you need to define `var countys` outside of `assets/`.

Comment: @muistooshort . Thanks for tip. But what is other places to define var countys if that is a javascript variable ? In view ? I am stuck..

Comment: Depends how often you need to use `countys` in your JavaScript. If you only need it in a couple places then you could do it in views (or maybe a partial that calls a helper to get the data). If you need it on almost every page then maybe roll it into your layouts (or arrange to get that data available when you compile your assets).